# How do I call a classes method from another class without initialising the first class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

I have something like the following:

```
class Class1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('I've init-ed')
    def print_me(self, string):
        print(string)

class Class2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Class 2 init')
    def print_me_from_other_class(self, string):
        Class1().print_me(string)
```

And then if I call something like:

```
test = Class2()
test.print_me_from_other_class('TEST')
```

then I get:

```
Class 2 init
I've init-ed
TEST
```

What I want to do is call the method from Class1 from the method in Class2 but without calling the **init** from class 1. So I'd end up with:

```
Class 2 init
TEST
```

I've tried removing the brackets after Class1 in the print_me_from_another_class(self, string) function so it says:

```
print_me_from_another_class(self, string):
    Class1.print_me(string)
```

But that throws the error:

```
TypeError: print_me() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'
```

Any ideas? Or is this a bad way to go about things? Seems like it will save rewriting code so should be a good thing.

EDIT:

I've worked out I need to pass the instance of Class2 to the function so that the function in Class2 becomes:

```
def print_me_from_other_class(self, string):
    Class1.print_me(self, string)
```

And it works! But I still want to know if this is a good way of doing things?

Comment: If you want to use an instance method without an instance, then it shouldn't be an instance method.

Comment: What the others say and `self.method()` is just short for `klass.method(self)` which allows you to call `Class1.print_me(self, string)` from within Class2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION

Thanks all for your help, I have a better understanding of it now. What I did in the end as suggested in comments was to remove these particular methods from the classes and make them global functions. I actually went through and removed all methods that weren't specifically referencing self (or made sense to leave them as class methods) and made them global. Looking at it now I think this is a better way to structure the code.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Note the "self" argument in print_me - this means that the function *must* be called on a specific instance of Class1.  What you want is a static function.  The code below demonstrates this.

```
class Class1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("I've init-ed")
    @staticmethod
    def print_me(string):
        print(string)

class Class2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Class 2 init')
    def print_me_from_other_class(self, string):
        Class1.print_me(string)


test = Class2()
test.print_me_from_other_class('TEST')
```

Output:

```
Class 2 init
TEST
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be called on an instance of class1.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how would you do so without getting a TypeError?

Comment: Exactly as the op demonstrates. `Class1.class_one_method(class_two_instance)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that only works if Class2 inherits from Class1.  Otherwise you get "TypeError: unbound method print_me2() must be called with Class1 instance as first argument (got Class2 instance instead)".

Comment: Ah, you are using Python 2. That no longer applies, there are no more unbound methods, it is just a plain function

Comment: In Python 2, you'd have to use `Class1.__dict__['class_one_method'](class_two_instance)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code block is `Class1.print_me(string)` creates new object, thats why init method is get called to avoid this. The simple solution is to use the inheritance.

```
class Class1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Ive init-ed')
    def print_me(self, string):
        print(string)

class Class2(Class1):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Class 2 init')
    def print_me_from_other_class(self, string):
        self.print_me(string)
obj=Class2()
obj2.print_me_from_other_class("hi")
```

you can directly call the base  class function as well
    `obj2.print_me("hello")`

Answer (score 0):

has you tried with @staticmethod ? something like:

```
class C1:
 def __init__(self):
  print "C1 INIT"
 def f(self):
  C2.c()

class C2:
 def __init__(self):
  print "C2 INIT"
 @staticmethod
 def c():
  print "method c from C2"
```

The @staticmethod decorator is for make static methods, in general this kind of methods are usefull when you want to call a method wothout initialize the class. Is a good approach for organize the functions.